# Proof for the Beta distribution

Tags: probability, statistics

I was looking for the proof for expectation for the beta distribution and found this.
[image: beta distribution]
<sub>(source: [statlect.com](http://images1.statlect.com/beta_distribution__40.png))</sub>

I don't understand how they went from the third to last step to the second to last step. Also what is that upside L called?

Comment: The "upside L" is the Gamma function. See for example [this](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gamma_function). One of the [properties](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Beta_function#Properties) of the Beta function is that $B(x,y)=\frac{\Gamma(x)\Gamma(y)}{\Gamma(x+y)}$.

Comment: Upside down $L$ is called Gamma

Comment: Okay so L is the gamma function. Then how does the proof go from the third to last step to the second to last step?

Comment: @Undergradstudent http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Beta_function

Comment: Okay got it. The property I was looking for was $\Gamma(\alpha +1)= \alpha \Gamma(\alpha)$

Comment: As written on the side???